# looping through columns and adjusting values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with around 100,000 rows and 1,000 columns and need to make some adjustments based on the existing data. How do I best approach this? Most of the changes will follow this basic formula:

1. search a column (or two or three) to see if a condition is met
2. if met, change the values of dozens or hundreds of columns in that row

This is my best attempt, where I created a list of the columns and was looking to see whether the first column contained the value 1. Where it did, I wanted to just add some number.  That part worked, but it only worked on the FIRST row, not on all the 1s in the column. To fix that, I think I need to create a loop where I have the second [i] that goes through all the rows, but I wasn't sure if I was approaching the entire problem incorrectly. FWIW, test_cols = list of columns and testing_2 is my df.

```
      def try_this(test_cols):
         for i in range(len(test_cols)):
             if i == 0 and testing_2[test_cols[i]][i] == 1:            
                 testing_2[test_cols[i]][i]=testing_2[test_cols[i]][i]+78787
         i+=1
         return test_cols
```

Edit/example:

```
       Year   Month    Mean_Temp 
City   

Madrid  1999   Jan     7--this value should appear twice       
Bilbao  1999   Jan     9--appear twice
Madrid  1999   Feb     9
Bilbao  1999   Feb     10
 .        .     .      .
 .        .     .      .
 .        .     .      .
Madrid  2000   Jan     6.8--this value should go away
Bilbao  2000   Jan     9.2--gone
```

So I would need to do something like (using your answer):

```
def alter(row):
     if row['Year'] == 2000 and row['Month'] == 'Jan':
         row['Mean_Temp'] = row['Mean_Temp'] #from year 1999!
         return row['Mean_Temp']  
     else:
         return row['Mean_Temp']
```

Comment: A good solution depends on the *particulars* of the condition and calculation you wish to perform. For example, the `if i==0` condition means the `for-loop` does something non-trivial only on the first iteration. So you really don't need the `for-loop`. Also, why augment `i` outside the `for-loop`? Why return `test_cols` if it is never modified?

Comment: @unutbu Starting with the whys: this is probably the result of me modifying some code from a groupby.apply function that i found here and used previously. The particulars will always be of the general format: 'if year = x' or 'if year = x and month = y' where year and month are columns in the DF. The calculation will be less of a formula and more like small shifts: replace values from 100 columns where year = x and month = y with values from those identical columns but a different year and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by creating a function and applying it. Suppose you want to increase column 'c' by a factor of 10 if the corresponding row in 'a' or 'b' is an even number.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[3,6,8,12], 'c':[1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def alter(row):
    if row['a']%2 == 0 or row['b']%2 == 0:
        return row['b']*10
    else:
        return row['b']

df['c'] = df.apply(alter, axis=1)
```

would create a df that looks like,

```
   a   b    c
0  1   3    3
1  2   6   60
2  3   8   80
3  4  12  120
```

Edit to add:
If you want to apply values from other parts of the df you could put those in a dict and then pass that into your apply function.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Cities':['Madrid', 'Balbao'] * 3, 'Year':[1999] * 4 + [2000] * 2,
        'Month':['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jan'],
        'Mean_Temp':[7, 9, 9, 10, 6.8, 9.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[['Cities', 'Year', 'Month', 'Mean_Temp']]

#create dicitonary with the values from 1999
edf = df[df.Year == 1999]
keys = zip(edf.Cities, edf.Month)
values = edf.Mean_Temp
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))


def alter(row, dictionary):
    if row['Year'] == 2000 and row['Month'] == 'Jan':
        return dictionary[(row.Cities, row.Month)]
    else:
        return row['Mean_Temp']

df['Mean_Temp'] = df.apply(alter, args = (dictionary,), axis=1)
```

Which gives you a df that looks like,

```
   Cities  Year Month  Mean_Temp
0  Madrid  1999   Jan          7
1  Balbao  1999   Jan          9
2  Madrid  1999   Feb          9
3  Balbao  1999   Feb         10
4  Madrid  2000   Jan          7
5  Balbao  2000   Jan          9
```

Of course you can change the parameters however you like. Hope this helps.

Comment: i think this should work but can't figure out how to get it to work for my problem. in this example, what if i kept the conditions the same, but instead of multiplying b by 10 i wished to return the value of b from a different row--say where a=1--leaving me nothing but 3's in column c.

Comment: i want to say something like: row['b'] = row['b'] where row['a']==1. is this possible or is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on exactly what you are trying to do. Could you add a specific example dataframe to your question and what you want done to it?